# How do I pass a non-mutable reference from Rust to a C-API that doesn't use const (even though it should)?

Tags: c, rust, ffi, unsafe, const-correctness

I have a wrapper around a C-API:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Request(http_request_t);
```

This wrapper provides several methods for interacting with the request:

```rust
impl Request {
    pub fn bytes_received(&self) -> usize {
        unsafe {
            http_request_bytes_received(&self.0 as *const http_request_t)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the C-API is not so strict about [`const`-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) and thus has a type signature of `usize http_request_bytes_received(*http_request_t)` which is dutifully converted by [`bindgen`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen) to `http_request_bytes_received(*mut http_request_t) -> usize`.

Now I could just cast my way out of this, but casting from `&T` to `*mut T` can [easily lead to undefined behaviour](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66136) (and it's a nasty cast). But it might be OK as `http_request_bytes_received` doesn't mutate `http_request_t`.

A possible alternative would be to use [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) so `http_request_t` is interior mutable:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Request(UnsafeCell<http_request_t>);

impl Request {
    pub fn bytes_received(&self) -> usize {
        unsafe {
            http_request_bytes_received(self.0.get())
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach sound and would there any serious downsides?

(I imagine it might limit some Rust optimizations and will make `Request` [`!Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html))

Comment: Could you write a trivial wrapper on the C side that casts away the `const`?  That should be perfectly fine.  Or, on any reasonable system, edit the header you feed to `bindgen` to include `const` in the declaration, pretending it was defined that way all along - technically not allowed but can't really fail.

Comment: @NateEldredge Probably the easiest way would be to [blocklist](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/blocklisting.html) the offending functions and then create the Rust definitions by hand. Downside is there's potentially a lot of them (over 1000 C functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: just cast it to `*mut T` and pass it to C.

Long answer:

It's best to first understand why casting `*const T` to `*mut T` is prone to undefined behaviour.

Rust's memory model ensures that a `&mut T` will not alias with anything else, so the compiler is free to, say, clobber T entirely and then restore its content, and the programmer could not observe that behaviour. If a `&mut T` and `&T` co-exists and point to the same location, undefined behaviour arises because what will happen if you read from `&T` while compiler clobbers `&mut T`? Similarly, if you have `&T`, the compiler assumes no one will modify it (excluding interior mutability through `UnsafeCell`), and undefined behaviour arise if the memory it points to is modified.

With the background, it's easy to see why `*const T` to `*mut T` is dangerous -- you cannot dereference the resulting pointer. If you ever dereference the `*mut T`, you've obtained a `&mut T`, and it'll be UB. However, the casting operation itself is safe, and you can safely cast the `*mut T` back to `*const T` and dereference it.

This is Rust semantics; on the C-side, the guarantee about `T*` is very weak. If you hold a `T*`, the compiler cannot assume there are no sharers. In fact, the compiler cannot even assert that it points to valid address (it could be null or past-the-end pointer). C compiler cannot generate store instructions to the memory location unless the code write to the pointer explicitly.

The weaker meaning of `T*` in C-side means that it won't violate Rust's assumption about semantics of `&T`. You can safely cast `&T` to `*mut T` and pass it to C, provided that C-side never modifies the memory pointed by the pointer.

Note that you can instruct the C compiler that the pointer won't alias with anything else with `T * restrict`, but as the C code you mentioned is not strict with `const`-correctness, it probably does not use `restrict` as well.